# On a property of a Special Fibonacci Sequence.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Let $\{F_n\}, n\in \mathbb{N}$ be the sequence of Fibonacci numbers such that $F_1=1$, $F_2=1$ and $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ $\forall n\geq2$.

Define a new sequence $\{S_n\}$ such that $S_n=F_n+k$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k$ is a fixed natural number.

Now the question is: What are the values of $k$ such that, for every prime $p$, there exist an $N\in  \mathbb{N}$, such that $p|S_N$ ?

Can we give a pattern for all such values?

Comment: Can we have at least _one_ such value beyond 0, to begin with?

Comment: Yes k=2 is one of them